# Reduce the sum in log

Tags: calculus, summation

$$1+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 2^2}+ \frac{1}{5 \cdot 2^4}+ \frac{1}{7 \cdot 2^6}+ ....=$$

Attemp: As
\begin{align*}
1+\frac1{3\cdot 2^2}+\frac1{5\cdot2^4}+\frac1{7\cdot 2^6}+\cdots&=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac1{(2n+1)2^{2n}}\\
&=2\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(1/2)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
\end{align*}

How do I do this log summation?

Comment: (The exact same method with $1/4$ instead of $1/2$.)

Comment: If you want to compute this sum, note that it is the sum $\sum_{n odd} \frac{2^{-n}}{n}= 
\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{2^{-n}}{n}-\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{2^{-2n}}{2n}$.

You can solve this by noting that $(\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{x^{-n}}{n})' = -\sum_{n \geq 0} x^{-n}$, then doing term by term integration to find the original sum and plugging in $x=  1/2$